# How to justify that the following system of PDE only admits linear solutions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, semi-riemannian-geometry

I have the following system of partial differential equations:

$$
\frac{\partial\Lambda^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}=
$$
$$
\small
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh\phi_{0}&\sinh\phi_{1}&\sinh\phi_{2}&\sinh\phi_{3}\\
\sin\theta_{0}\cos\omega_{0}\sinh\phi_{0}&\sin\theta_{1}\cos\omega_{1}\cosh\phi_{1}&\sin\theta_{2}\cos\omega_{2}\cosh\phi_{2}&\sin\theta_{3}\cos\omega_{3}\cosh\phi_{3}\\
\sin\theta_{0}\sin\omega_{0}\sinh\phi_{0}&\sin\theta_{1}\sinh\omega_{1}\cosh\phi_{1}&\sin\theta_{2}\sin\omega_{2}\cosh\phi_{2}&\sin\theta_{3}\sinh\omega_{3}\cosh\phi_{3}\\
\cos\theta_{0}\sinh\phi_{0}&\cos\theta_{1}\cosh\phi_{1}&\cos\theta_{2}\cosh\phi_{2}&\cos\theta_{3}\cosh\phi_{3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Where $\Lambda:\Bbb{R}^{4}\to\Bbb{R}^{4}$ is written as $\Lambda(x^{0},x^{1},x^{2},x^{3})=(\Lambda^{0},\Lambda^{1},\Lambda^{2},\Lambda^{3})$ and $\mu$ and $\nu$ denote respectively the rows and columns of the jacobian matrix. Is there any way by which I can say a priori that the hyperbolic and trigonometric angles do not depend themselves on the coordinates $(x^{0},x^{1},x^{2},x^{3})$ without, for example, computing the Schwartz conditions on the second derivatives for each and every one of them?
$$
\\
$$
Should it be necessary, the system itself is accompanied by the equations
$$
\cosh\phi_{0}\sinh\phi_{1}=\cosh\phi_{1}\sinh\phi_{0}\left[\sin\theta_{0}\sin\theta_{1}\cos(\omega_{0}-\omega_{1})+\cos\theta_{0}\cos\theta_{1}\right]\\
\\
\cosh\phi_{0}\sinh\phi_{2}=\cosh\phi_{2}\sinh\phi_{0}\left[\sin\theta_{0}\sin\theta_{2}\cos(\omega_{0}-\omega_{2})+\cos\theta_{0}\cos\theta_{2}\right]\\
\\
\cosh\phi_{0}\sinh\phi_{3}=\cosh\phi_{3}\sinh\phi_{0}\left[\sin\theta_{0}\sin\theta_{3}\cos(\omega_{0}-\omega_{3})+\cos\theta_{0}\cos\theta_{3}\right]\\
\\
\sinh\phi_{1}\sinh\phi_{2}=\cosh\phi_{1}\cosh\phi_{2}\left[\sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{2}\cos(\omega_{1}-\omega_{2})+\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}\right]\\
\\
\sinh\phi_{1}\sinh\phi_{3}=\cosh\phi_{1}\cosh\phi_{3}\left[\sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{3}\cos(\omega_{1}-\omega_{3})+\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{3}\right]\\
\\
\sinh\phi_{2}\sinh\phi_{3}=\cosh\phi_{2}\cosh\phi_{3}\left[\sin\theta_{2}\sin\theta_{3}\cos(\omega_{2}-\omega_{3})+\cos\theta_{2}\cos\theta_{3}\right]
$$

$$
\\
$$
P.S.: The solution to the equations represent the general form of the symmetry transformations of Minkowski spacetime.

$$\\$$
EDIT: The matrix and the equations that I wrote above are really a solution to the PDEs

$$
\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{0}}\right)^{2}-\left[\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{0}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{0}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{0}}\right)^{2}\right]=1\\
\\
\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{1}}\right)^{2}-\left[\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{1}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{1}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{1}}\right)^{2}\right]=-1\\
\\
\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{2}}\right)^{2}-\left[\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{2}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{2}}\right)^{2}\right]=-1\\
\\
\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{1}}\right)^{3}-\left[\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{3}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{3}}\right)^{3}+\left(\frac{\partial\Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{3}}\right)^{2}\right]=-1\\
\\
\\
\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{1}}=\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{1}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{1}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{1}}\\
\\
\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{2}}=\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{2}}\\
\\
\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{3}}=\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{3}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{3}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{0}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{3}}\\
\\
\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{1}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{2}}=\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{1}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{1}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{1}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{2}}\\
\\
\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{1}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{3}}=\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{1}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{3}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{1}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{3}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{1}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{3}}\\
\\
\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{0}}{\partial x^{3}}=\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{1}}{\partial x^{3}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{2}}{\partial x^{3}}+\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial \Lambda^{3}}{\partial x^{3}}
$$

I'm thinking that the actual system could actually be more significative than the solution I gave.

Comment: What is the relation between $x^\nu$ and $\phi_0,\phi_1,\ldots$ ?

Comment: The angles (both hyperbolic and trigonometric) may or may not be constants. If they are not constants, taking the second derivative should yield some information such as a new system of equations that can be  used to determine them. I'm quite sure that the latter would confirm (together with the six relations written below) that they ultimately are constant. But the  derived system is huge, and I'm looking  for a way to bypass its resolution.

Comment: Ok. So in general $\phi_i = \phi_i(x^0,\ldots,x^3)$ and similar for $\theta$ and $\omega$?

Comment: As long as we know, yes